# Why does my previously defined function expands/computes to itself?

Tags: coq, beginner

##### Problem

I have a function `leb` defined in one of the (transitively) imported file: `Types.v`. However, calling it in my current file (`Structures.v`) doesn't "evaluate" to a value. Instead, it expands to itself, which is unexpected.

To illustrate what I mean, here is the layout of the Coq project directory:
(Note: Relevant file content are quoted as strings.)

```
$PROJECT_ROOT
|- _Coqproject
   "-Q . DMFP"
|- Types.v
   "Fixpoint leb (n m : nat) : bool := ..."
|- Recursion.v
   "Require Export DMFP.Types. ..."
|- Structures.v
   "Require Export DMFP.Recursion. ..."
```

As you can see, the function `leb` is defined in `Types.v`. But when I tried to use it in `Structures.v`, it `computes` to itself:

```ml
Compute (leb 2 3).
```

gives this:

```
     = leb 2 3
     : bool
```

Then,

```ml
Print leb.
```

gives this:

```
*** [ leb : nat -> nat -> bool ]

Arguments leb (n m)%nat_scope
```

##### Questions

1. Why does `leb` expands to itself?
2. What does `*** [ leb : nat -> nat -> bool ]` mean with `Print leb.`?
3. How to make `leb` available in `Structures.v`, such that I can use `leb` as in `Types.v` where it is defined?

Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. I copied your file structure and defined `leb` as expected. The main difference was that I also added a `Makefile` ([this one](https://gitlab.com/ana-borges/WormsCoq/-/blob/master/Makefile), that I copied from somewhere but I don't remember where) and included the file names in the `_CoqProject` so that `make` could compile everything. Then I obtained the expected outputs in `Structures.v`, not the ones you did. **Question:** what happens when you `Compute` and `Print` in `Types.v`? Are you sure this is related to doing it on a different file?

Comment: Thanks, `Compute` and `Print` are indeed working fine in `Types.v`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your outputs are consistent with `leb` being defined as a parameter, not as a specific function. So, for example:

```
Parameter leb : nat -> nat -> bool.

Compute (leb 2 3).
(*     = leb 2 3
     : bool
*)

Print leb.
(*
*** [ leb : nat -> nat -> bool ]

Arguments leb (_ _)%nat_scope
*)
```

Compare with having an actual definition for `leb`:

```
Fixpoint leb (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true
  | S k =>
      match m with
      | O => false
      | S k' => leb k k'
      end
  end.

Compute (leb 2 3).
(*
     = true
     : bool
*)

Print leb.
(*
leb = 
fix leb (n m : nat) {struct n} : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => true
  | S k => match m with
           | 0 => false
           | S k' => leb k k'
           end
  end
     : nat -> nat -> bool

Arguments leb (n m)%nat_scope
*)
```

I'm guessing at this point, but here is what could have happened:

1. You stated the existence of `leb` in `Types.v` without giving it a definition (eg with `Fixpoint leb (n m : nat) : bool. Admitted.`)
2. You compiled `Types.v`
3. You went back to `Types.v` to fill in your definition of `leb`
4. You started working on `Structures.v` *without* compiling `Types.v` again, and so it was still using the old version where you hadn't filled in the definition for `leb` yet.

If this is not what's happening, then please provide more details. As I explained in my comment, I can't reproduce your data.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed your guess is right, after compiling `Types.v` and `Recursion.v` again, now the function can be used normally in `Structures.v`.

Comment: Not sure why, I thought Proof General will auto compile some `.v` files on demand. because when I'm just getting started yesterday, I started seeing `.vo` being produced without me invoking any command.

Comment: Another solution is to `make clean` and `make build` again.